# linear algebra : matrix decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $X \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n \times p}(\mathbb{R})$ a matrix such that $\mathrm{rank}(X)=p$. Let $S = \mathrm{I}_{n} - X \big( X^{\top} X \big)^{-1} X^{\top}$ be the orthogonal projection on $\big( \mathrm{Im}(X) \big)^{\perp}$ (where $\mathrm{Im}(X)$ denotes the column space of $X$).

I would like to prove that there always exists a matrix $A \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n \times (n-p)}(\mathbb{R})$ such that :

$$ S = A A^{\top} \quad \mathrm{and} \quad A^{\top} A = \mathrm{I}_{n} $$

Since $\dim \mathrm{Im}(X) = p$, we have : $\dim \big( \mathrm{Im}(X) \big)^{\perp} = n-p$. I would like to consider an orthonormal basis of $\big( \mathrm{Im}(X) \big)^{\perp}$ but I don't know how to use it.

[This is not a homework question even though it could be one]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_1,\ldots, v_p$ an orthonormal basis of ${\rm Im}(X)$ and $v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_n$ an orthonormal basis of ${\rm Im}(X)^\bot$. Let $A = (v_{p+1} \cdots v_n)$ the matrix which has the basis of ${\rm Im}(X)^\bot$ as columns. Then $A^\top A = {\rm Id}_{n-p}$, as the $v_i$ are orthonormal, on the other hand, we have for $i \le p$ that $A^\top v_i =0 $ and for $i > p $ that $A^\top v_i = e_{i-p}$ (the standard unit vector). That is 
$$ AA^\top v_i = \begin{cases} 0 & i \le p \\ Ae_{i-p} = v_i & i > p \end{cases} $$
That is $AA^\top$ is zero on ${\rm Im}(X)$ and the identity on ${\rm Im}(X)^\bot$, that is $AA^\top$ is equal to the projector onto ${\rm Im}(X)^\bot$, hence $AA^\top = S$.